# sqlite3 db created but table doesn't exist

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Using the built in command line tool for sqlite3 on a Mac, I ran the sql schema (created by a Lynda.com tutorial) below to create an sql database and the database  `bwrss.db` is showing as having been created in the downloads folder where the schema was located. I then ran this code, provided by the tutorial, which is supposed to read and display the feed ids inserted when I created the db

```
-(void) dispRow:(NSDictionary *) row {
    message(@"row %@ [%@]", row [@"title"], row [@"url"]);
}

-(void) testDatabase {
    RSSDB *db;
    NSString * dbfn = @"bwrss.db";

    db = [[RSSDB alloc] initWithRSSDBFilename:dbfn];
    message(@"RSSDB version %@", [db getVersion]);

    for (NSNumber *n in [db getFeedIDs]) {
        NSDictionary *feed = [db getFeedRow:n];
        [self dispRow:feed];
    }
}
```

When I run the code, however, it only displays the version number (from line 4 of the testDatabase method) but nothing else. It shows this error in the xCode console.

```
2014-03-21 10:00:51.052 Testbed[1381:a0b] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: main.feed) CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS feedUrl ON feed(url)
2014-03-21 10:00:51.056 Testbed[1381:a0b] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: feed) SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)
2014-03-21 10:00:51.058 Testbed[1381:a0b] rowFromPreparedQuery: could not get row: no such table: feed
```

The Lynda.com instructor says that if it only shows the version, it means you might have to delete the app from the simulator so that new data is loaded in, as we have created several versions of the app in earlier sections.

The error message says, "no such table: feed" yet the db is shown as having been created.  Can you explain why this is happening? The db file is not in the same directory as the project but it's my understanding that it doesn't have to be.

Schema

```
-- bwrss.sql
-- by Bill Weinman - http://bw.org/contact/
-- SQLite database for BW RSS iOS app
-- Copyright 2009-2010 The BearHeart Group LLC

-- This script creates the database tables for the BW RSS application
-- and seeds the feed table with initial records. 

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS feed;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;

CREATE TABLE feed (
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    -- unique id for this record
    url     TEXT,                   -- url for data
    title   TEXT,                   -- title of the feed
    desc    TEXT,                   -- description of the feed
    pubdate TEXT,                   -- feed last update date/time
    stamp   TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE TABLE item (
    id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    -- unique id for this record
    feed_id INTEGER,                -- feed id
    url     TEXT,                   -- url of item
    title   TEXT,                   -- title of the item
    desc    TEXT,                   -- description of the item
    pubdate TEXT,                   -- publication date/time of this item
    stamp   TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX feedUrl ON feed(url);

INSERT INTO feed (url, title, desc) VALUES (
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/lyndablog',
    'lynda.blog',
    'the blog of lynda.com'
);

INSERT INTO feed (url, title, desc) VALUES (
    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/lyndacom-new-releases',
    'lynda.com New Releases',
    'lynda.com New Releases RSS Feed.'
);

INSERT INTO feed (url, title, desc) VALUES (
    'http://billweinman.wordpress.com/feed/',
    'Bill Weinman''s Technology Blog',
    'because it''s all about the data'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem if i open in a ios simulator.

```
2014-10-23 00:47:34.166 RSS[10465:544566] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: main.feed) CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS feedUrl ON feed(url)
2014-10-23 00:47:34.167 RSS[10465:544566] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: feed) SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)
2014-10-23 00:47:34.167 RSS[10465:544566] rowFromPreparedQuery: could not get row: no such table: feed
2014-10-23 00:47:34.167 RSS[10465:544566] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: feed) SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)
2014-10-23 00:47:34.167 RSS[10465:544566] rowFromPreparedQuery: could not get row: no such table: feed
2014-10-23 00:47:34.168 RSS[10465:544566] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: feed) SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)
2014-10-23 00:47:34.168 RSS[10465:544566] rowFromPreparedQuery: could not get row: no such table: feed
2014-10-23 00:47:34.169 RSS[10465:544566] bindSQL: could not prepare statement (no such table: feed) SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)
2014-10-23 00:47:34.169 RSS[10465:544566] rowFromPreparedQuery: could not get row: no such table: feed
```

but in a normal device its working

maybe this is the reason in methods:

- BWDB.m / - (NSNumber *) insertRow:(NSDictionary *) record
- BWDB.m / - (void) updateRow:(NSDictionary *) recordforRowID:(NSNumber *) rowID

```
[self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] withVargs:(va_list)dValues.mutableBytes];
```

error:

```
.../BWDB/BWDB.m:276:48: Used type 'va_list' (aka '__builtin_va_list') where arithmetic or pointer type is required
```